# Flash refuses to work on Firefox Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: firefox, 18.04, flash

I'm aware this has been asked a hundred times but it seems like none of the solutions that have been posted for other people are working for me.

Adobe must've changed something in the past year because half of the questions are completely outdated.

Here's what I've done:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install adobe-flashplugin browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash
```

According to most tutorials online this should work. But it doesn't.

I tried installing

flashplugin-installer

but not only does it not work it also gives me an "update" message every time I start, but when I choose to update nothing happens.

I checked here https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player.html and firefox is not recognizing flash player to be installed.

I'm completely lost and I feel like I installed and uninstalled so much stuff that at this point it's going to be impossible to actually fix this.

I don't know what to do anymore, please help.

EDIT: Flash works perfectly on Chromium. I don't know if Chromium still comes with its internal version of Flash, but it seems to be working just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a new issue. :)

`browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash` does currently not work with recent versions of Firefox; please see [bug #1778041](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1778041).

Solution: Uninstall `browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash`

*Edit:*

After a long issue tracking talk in the comments on this answer I'd like to add:

The Flash plugin does not work together with the Firefox snap, at least not yet. So if you want to use Flash with your Firefox browser, install and use Firefox from the Ubuntu archive:

```
sudo apt install firefox
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79582/discussion-on-answer-by-gunnar-hjalmarsson-flash-refuses-to-work-on-firefox-ubun).

Comment: Uninstalling the plugin has worked perfectly for me on Ubuntu 18.04 with Firefox 61.0.1 (version from the official repos). If anyone is wondering what the command is to do that: `sudo apt remove browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash`

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing installing flash via the flashplugin-installer worked fine with Ubuntu 18.04 64-bit and Firefox 60.

Browsing to https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player.html works fine.

I just had to enable permissions to allow the plugin for the site as per: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/why-do-i-have-click-activate-plugins

```
flashplugin-installer: processing...
flashplugin-installer: downloading http://archive.canonical.com/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flashplugin_20180607.1.orig.tar.gz
Get:1 http://archive.canonical.com/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flashplugin_20180607.1.orig.tar.gz [30.5 MB]
Fetched 30.5 MB in 19s (1,625 kB/s)                                                                                                                            
Installing from local file /var/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloads/partial/adobe-flashplugin_20180607.1.orig.tar.gz
Flash Plugin installed.
Setting up libpangox-1.0-0:amd64 (0.0.2-5) ...
Setting up libpango1.0-0:amd64 (1.40.14-1) ...
Setting up flashplugin-installer (30.0.0.113ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
```